# Border Pane with Swipe Animation Javafx

Tags: animation, javafx, properties, key-value, borderpane

I am working on a Javafx application that features a main borderpane. There are different panes on the top and the right side of the application. The center has a main StackPane on which I add and remove panes as necessary. I have created a swipe animation that will swipe one pane out as another comes in for this stackpane in the center.

The problem is that the swipe animation is based on the translateX property of each pane. These properties extend from one end of the main border pane to the other. This means that as I am swiping in and out, the panes go over the panels of the main borderpane on the sides as well.

I am not sure how to fix this. I considered putting some sort of Group to encapsulate the panes I am adding to the center that would keep the animation within just the nodes in the group. The problem with that is that Groups are not resizable so when I expand and shrink the window, the panes do not grow with it. My temporary fix is to make the side panels invisible while the animations swipe. However, I would like to find either a way to encapsulate these nodes while allowing them still to fit the size of the center or a way to set my translateX property to fill only the sides of the center stack.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you!

This is my swipe function:

```
    root.getChildren().add(pane1);

    KeyFrame start = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
            new KeyValue(pane1.translateXProperty(), root.getWidth()),
            new KeyValue(pane2.translateXProperty(), 0));
    KeyFrame end = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
            new KeyValue(pane1.translateXProperty(), 0),
            new KeyValue(pane2.translateXProperty(), -root.getWidth()));
    Timeline slide = new Timeline(start, end);
    slide.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            root.getChildren().remove(pane2);
            for(Node b : buttonBar.getButtons()){
                b.setDisable(false);
                dvs.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

here, root is the outer pane that these nodes are on, pane1 is the destination pane, and pane2 is the pane that is being swiped out.

Comment: I am guessing here, but have you tried moving the center node to back? That way it will be behind the side nodes. Make sure the side node backgrounds are not transparent.

Comment: I did something similar [here](https://github.com/sedj601/SlotMachineExample), but you will have to go through the code to try to figure it out.